# Modx tv текстовый редактор не выводит 

Tags: modx, tinymce

Может кто-то встречался с такой проблемой. 
На modx revo установлен редактор текста tinymce. Создаю TV - текстовый редактор. Передаю его в сниппет:

```
[[!costhotel? &opisanie=[[*opisanie]] ]]
```

И вывожу в сниппете таким образом:

```
$opisanie = $modx->getOption('opisanie',$scriptProperties);
echo $opisanie;
```

но когда в поле вводишь текст с катринкой, то не выводится ничего. Если без картинки то нормально выводится текст с тегами.

Answer (score 3):

в принципе понятно после &opisanie= нужно ставить обратные апострофы это возле кнопочки 1 и заключать этот `[[*opisanie]]` в них

```
[[!costhotel? &opisanie=`[[*opisanie]]` ]]
```